# WCF Service behind ISA

Tags: wcf, isaserver

I have created a wcf service, successfully deployed to a development server(not behind an ISA Server) and was able to add a service reference to to the service in a test web app. My network administrators deployed the same service to our staging box which is behind an ISA server, when I try to add a service reference through vs2008 or use the svcutil utility I get the following:

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
'http://tstsrvr.Testdmz.staging:5910/myService/TestService.svc?wsdl'.
There was an error downloading 'http://tstsrvr.Testdmz.staging:5910/myService/TestService.svc?wsdl'.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'tstsrvr.Testdmz.staging'
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
'https://stg-ww2.Test.com/myservice/Testservice.svc'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
'https://stg-ww2.Test.com/myservice/Testservice.svc'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and 
adding the service reference again.

I am able to hit the .svc link through a web browser and then able to click the link

svcutil.exe https://stg-ww2.myserver.com/TestService/TestService.svc?wsdl

which seems to work fine, I am pretty new to wcf so any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: can you post the config for your service?

Answer (score 0):

svcutil.exe uses IE's proxy settings.

Uncheck "use a proxy server" from IE > Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings and see if that solves your problem.

If you still have a problem, consider adding the system.net section in your configuration file.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy >
      <proxy autoDetect ="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

and set

```
<transport proxyCredentialType="Windows"/>
```